# Rewrite specific part of URL address

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I can manually change every piece of code in my Codeigniter script (which is huge) or I can possibly do it with .htaccess.

Is there a way to change a part of URL, mask it so that the `www.page.com/athlete` becomes `www.page.com/product`? However I don't wish to go into the code meaning that links leading to `www.page.com/athlete` would still work, only difference would be in the URL bar where it would show `www.page.com/product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it, with Routes. Add this to ./application/config/routes.php

```
$route['product'] = 'athlete';
```

Now, whenever you visit /products it will load the /athlete controller.

You could maybe try something like this. Check if the URI segment is "athlete", if it is, redirect them to "product" which you have set to point to the athlete controller. Like this;

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Check if the URI is athlete, if it is, redirect them to product
    // But, product is this controller, which is defined in the routes
    if ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'athlete')
    {
        redirect('product');
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, very elegant, however I still need to change links on my webpage, correct?

Comment: Yes, the URLs in your links will still link to the "athlete" controller.

Comment: You could check, in the class constructor what the uri_segment is, and redirect them to the uri you like. I will update my answer with an example.